# How to use std::bind to bind a function with object pointer param?

Tags: c++, c++11

Following is my code:

```
class A {};
class Test
{
public:
    template <class TClass>
    Test(TClass* _objPointer, void(TClass::*_func)(A*))
    {
        mEventFunction = std::bind(_func, _objPointer);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(A*)> mEventFunction;
};

class Demo
{
public:
    void BindFunc()
    {
        mTest = new Test(this, &Demo::testFunc);
    }
    void testFunc(A*)
    {

    }
private:
    Test* mTest;
};
```

What I want to achieve is BindFunc() in Demo class. But this code run with lot of error message:
 error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
......

Comment: `std::bind(_func, _objPointer, std::placeholders::_1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include a [`std::placeholders::_1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) to account for the `A*` argument that you haven't bound yet:

```
#include <functional>

class A {};
class Test
{
public:
    template <class TClass>
    Test(TClass* _objPointer, void(TClass::*_func)(A*))
    {
        mEventFunction = std::bind(_func, _objPointer, std::placeholders::_1);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(A*)> mEventFunction;
};

class Demo
{
public:
    void BindFunc()
    {
        mTest = new Test(this, &Demo::testFunc);
    }
    void testFunc(A*)
    {

    }
private:
    Test* mTest;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b2e7532105b5d9d)

I think it's a little clearer that you need some placeholder for `A*` if we used a lambda instead ([Demo2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1be387c53aa2abed)):

```
template <class TClass>
Test(TClass* _objPointer, void(TClass::*_func)(A*))
{
    mEventFunction = [_objPointer, _func](A* _a){(_objPointer->*_func)(_a);};
}
```

Here the lambda accepts an argument for `A*`, which is what you wanted. I actually recommend the lambda approach over `std::bind` in nearly all use cases.

Comment: Kudos for preferring the lambda to `bind`.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer!